# how to make android app fetch content from dedicated internet page?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-internet

I am planning to create a small review app in android that fetches movie reviews from a webserver/page. So how should i design the online component? The online part need not be visible through browsers, but available to the app. So, basically how should i put the data on the server? Json or simple web page or database tables?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best approach to achieve this is to create some (REST or not) web service and as an output format use json.

architecture like this: mobile_app <---> web service <---> database

You could also have some other program which for example will be creating some json file on ftp server.

If you have webpage already in created in php, python, ruby etc you can create some API for your mobie app. For example you have some page with movie reviews with your-domain/reviews.html URL

you can create similar endpoint for your mobile app with you-domain/reviews.json which will gives you some json dedicated for your mobile.

Comment: so if i have a reviews.html, should i have to sode the entire reviews.json or is there any html to json parsers?

Comment: if you have static html page I suggest to create json file based on data from your html. just prepare the json structure for your needs and thats all. I dont know if there is any html to json parser but you always can as google for that.